# How to make the array data to array based on the id in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, yup, react-hook-form

```
const applications = [
{
 id: 1,
 name: 'app1',
},
{
 id: 2,
 name: 'app2',
},
{
 id: 3,
 name: 'app3',
}
]

....
const form = 
config = [
      {
        label: "Application",
        name: "applications",
        type: "select",
        config: {
          labelKey: 'name',
          valueKey: 'id',
          multiple: true
        },
        options: applications,
        rule: yup.array(yup.string()).min(1, 'Application field must have at least 1 or more items').required(),
      },
]
```

What I'm trying to do here is when I submit the form. it should be based on the id
like for example in select application I select the `app1` and `app2`.

then when submitting the form it will be like this `[{id: 1}, {id: 2}]`

Comment: `const data = [].map((i) => ({ id: i.id }));` and then filter it

Answer (score 1):

You should map your RHF form data inside the callback of the `handleSubmit` method like this:

```js
const onSubmit = handleSubmit(formValues => ({
  ...formValues,
  applications: formValues.applications.map(({ id }) => id),
}));
```